# I want the latest updates!

Tags: 14.04, updates

I am a new user here and I wanted to know if I could update from Ubuntu 14.04 to later versions without reinstalling Ubuntu to my system?

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and change:

```
[DEFAULT]
Prompt=lts
```

to:

```
[DEFAULT]
Prompt=normal
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and finally:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

If it tells you `command not found` for `do-release-upgrade`, install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Comment: FYI `do-release-upgrade` does not require sudo, it will make its own call to sudo.  The steps prior to running `do-release-upgrade` in this answer *usually* aren't required, but this answer is comprehensive enough to cover all bases.

Comment: @thomasrutter I'm not running Ubuntu, so I wouldn't know if `do-release-upgrade` needs `sudo`, but thank you, I will edit it! They probably aren't required, spare the change to the `release-upgrades` file, but it's better to provide as much as possible in my answer.